# How to conditionally display text string in Eval - C#

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, eval

I have a div in which i assign some text using the following dynamic text.

```
<div class="name"><%#Eval("Name")%></div>
```

Now i want to add '...' if the length of the parmater 'Name' > 12. I tried the following code but it fails.

```
<% #Eval("Name").ToString().Length <= 12 ? Eval("Name") : Eval("Name").ToString().Substring(0, 12)+"..." % >
```

Comment: Include error information

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this in the markup.  This logic should be in the code behind when you're assigning the value to `Name`.

Comment: you need to wrap that around single quotes like this 
`<div class="name">'<%#Eval("Name")%>'</div>`

Comment: @DJKRAZE No he doesn't.    It would just add literal single quotes in the output.

Comment: That's really odd.. because I use a similar thing and it works for me on my end.. however I am doing this inside of an ItemTemplate.. Disregard

Comment: How does it fail? It should work, there are other options here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448511/how-to-limit-text-string-in-eval

Comment: I used Servy's suggestion of handling this in code rather than in markup